# "top x% this month" appears lower even though my rank is higher

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, reputation-leagues, top-users

I was active mainly in Stack Overflow but recently joined the beta Arabic.SE.

In Arabic.SE I am holding the [1st rank](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/369/month/arabic/2015-07-01/42#42) monthly, however it shows in my profile that I am in the top 8% this month:

> [image]

In the other hand, on SO, it shows I am in 2% this month:

> [image]

How is that possible? Shouldn't it be a better percentage where my rank is higher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Stack Overflow this is the calculation:

- Your rank: 3,118
- Users with reputation activity: 158,471

> 3,118 / 158,471 = 1,96%

And Arabic Language:

- Your rank: 1
- Users with reputation activity: 13

> 1 / 13 = 7,69%

The point in this is: there are much less active users on Arabic than on SO, so your top % will be lower on Arabic, even when you are first.

Comment: You are right. I saw only 13 users in the list. So 1/13 = 0.076% = 8%.  Thanks.

Comment: when users are less then 100 users, 1st rank user percentage will be more than 1%.

Comment: That would be it then indeed. Added the figures to the post.